# in wpf Treeview, How I can combine multiple Items as childes into one grouped Item in Lower Level of treeview not upper level?

Tags: wpf, treeview, parent-child, contentpresenter, itemspresenter

I need to affect the TreeviewItem Class or make inherited Class, so that I can Implement grouping for multi childes as ItemsPresenter into one grouped item like the following figure:

[image]

Probably, Adding another ContentPresenter in Lower-Level of TreeView Template below than Itemspresenter is one solution OR may be to add new Parent Variable to be shared between multichildes in treeview for the inherited TreeviewItem Class, What Would be the Solution for that? Any Idea Please !

I am trying to Represent more Efficient Treeview logic!

Comment: Please start with the ViewModel DM classes. Once you have it we will have a base to start with. You have mentioned using Parent Property. This is helpful because we have access to different entities in one context.

Comment: Yes, The View model DM classes seems the solution in my case, would also be great to represent the model graphically so that all relations and defined variables are there! Thank you Mr. Mark Feldman for supporting ideas and advices you give!